# Grouping criteria in Sqlite query

Tags: grouping, criteria

I have a table like this.

| ID | TYPE | PRİCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NOTEBOOK | 400 |
| 2 | NOTEBOOK | 400 |
| 3 | NOTEBOOK | 600 |
| 4 | DUSTER | 200 |
| 5 | DUSTER | 350 |
| 6 | PEN | 1500 |
| 7 | PEN | 2500 |

```
**The query I use is**

*SELECT TYPE AS TYPE , COUNT(TYPE) AS İNT , SUM(PRICE) AS TOTAL
WHERE TYPE LIKE 'NOTEBOOK' AND TYPE LIKE 'DUSTER'
FROM TBL GROUP BY TYPE ORDER BY TYPE ASC*
```

I want to get results like below by grouping with Sqlite query.

| TYPE | İNT | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DUSTER | 2 | 550 |
| PEN | 2 | 4000 |